# Disable horizontal drag scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I have a div which has an `overflow: hidden;` but when I drag with my mouse to the right it still moves to the right while I disabled scrolling with the overflow option in CSS. I tried to use jQuery:

```
$('.wrapper').mousemove(function(ev){
    $(this).scrollLeft(0);
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

But it doesn't work. Does anyone know a solution?

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MrAtiebatie/P68Jv/embedded/result

Comment: Can you show us code... without that it will be hard to help you.. also a working demo of issue using jsfiddle.net will be helpfull too

Comment: isnt 'ev' missing in function arguments? function(ev){...}

Comment: Sorry I use ev in my code I only forget it here above. Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MrAtiebatie/P68Jv/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this javascript code:

```
    var element = document.getElementByClass("wrapper");

    element.onscroll = function () {
       element.scrollTo(0,0);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the scroll event is not fired when I drag.

Comment: Post the html/CSS code, is hard to help you with only this informations

Comment: I already commented a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MrAtiebatie/P68Jv/embedded/result

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it. Anyway I did not understand. I see no scroll in the div that contains the list

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. It wasn't the `.wrapper` or the `ul` that was scrolling but the 
`.holder` So I fixed it with jQuery. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/P68Jv/4/embedded/result/) the result. Thank you all for helping.